# Send web header collection

Tags: c#, wcf

How to send web header collection from rest Service to remoting service?
I have tried to send web headers using below code but its not working.

```
System.Net.WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(uri);
request.Headers.Add("myheader", "myheader_value");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below sample

```
public RemotingServiceClient serviceClient = new RemotingServiceClient();
public void Demo()
{
    using (OperationContextScope scope = new  OperationContextScope(serviceClient.InnerChannel))
    {
        MessageHeader<string> header = new MessageHeader<string>("HeaderValue1");
        var v1 = header.GetUntypedHeader("HeaderName1", "RemotingService");

        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(v1);

        header = new MessageHeader<string>("HeaderValue2");
        var v2 = header.GetUntypedHeader("HeaderName2", "RemotingService");

        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(v2);

        //IMP: To send headers make sure to call service in this block only.
        //Keep unique uri name "RemotingService"
        return serviceClient.MyRemotingServiceCall();
    }
}
```

It's working for me as expected